# Debian: sftp transfer over bash

Tags: debian, sftp, transfer

I know that I can transfer files over sftp username@server, but is it possible to send the password with? something Like sftp --password test username@server

I already searched but I didn't find an easy way.

Regards,
Akitoyo

Answer (score 0):

Use ssh keys. If you really want password based login you could use [expect](https://wiki.debian.org/Expect).

Nevertheless this question should be on superuser/serverfault not stackoverflow.